# CountVectorize vocabulary specification for bigrams python

Tags: python, countvectorizer

I am trying to get a sparse matrix of term counts of a huge (~160.000) number of documents.

I cleaned text and want to loop over all documents (i.e. count vectorize one at a time and append the resulting 1xN arrays. The following code works for the word by word case, but not for bigrams:

```
cv1 = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(stop_words=None,vocabulary=dictionary1)
cv2 = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(stop_words=None,vocabulary=dictionary2)

for row in range(start,end+1):
    report_name = fund_reports_table.loc[row, "report_names"]
    raw_report = open("F:/EDGAR_ShareholderReports/" + report_name, 'r', encoding="utf8").read()

    ## word for word
    temp = cv1.fit_transform([raw_report]).toarray()
    res1 = np.concatenate((res1,temp),axis=0)

    ## big grams
    bigram=set()
    sentences = raw_report.split(".")
    for line in sentences:
        token = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        bigram = bigram.union(set(list(ngrams(token, 2)))  )

    temp = cv2.fit_transform(list(bigram)).toarray()
    res2=np.concatenate((res2,temp),axis=0)
```

Python returns

```
"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'"
```

presumably because the way I feed data into the bigram vectorizecounter is invalid.

"raw_report" is a string. The one-by-word dictionary is:

```
dictionary1 =['word1', 'words2',...]
```

dictionary2 is similar but based on bigrams constructed by merging all bigrams of all documents (and keeping unique values, done in a previous) such that the resulting structure is

```
dictionary2 =[('word1','word2'),('wordn','wordm'),...]
```

The document bigram has the same structure, that's why I am puzzled why python won't accept the input. Is there a way to fix this or is my entire approach not very pythonic and starts to backfire?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Remark: I understand that I could do the entire process in a more elaborate CountVectorize command (i.e. the cleaning and tokenization and counting in one step), but I would much prefer too be able to do this myself (in order to see&store intermediate outputs). Also I am afraid I run into memory issues given the large amount of text I use.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the fact that your dictionary2 is based on tuples. Here is a minimalist example, that shows that this works when the bi-grams are strings. If you want to process each file separately, you can pass it to vectorizer.transform() as a list.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

Doc1 = 'Wimbledon is one of the four Grand Slam tennis tournaments, the others being the Australian Open, the French Open and the US Open.'
Doc2 = 'Since the Australian Open shifted to hardcourt in 1988, Wimbledon is the only major still played on grass'
doc_set = [Doc1, Doc2]

my_vocabulary= ['Grand Slam', 'Australian Open', 'French Open', 'US Open']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2))
vectorizer.fit_transform(my_vocabulary)
term_count = vectorizer.transform(doc_set)

# Show the index key for each bigram
vectorizer.vocabulary_
Out[11]: {'grand slam': 2, 'australian open': 0, 'french open': 1, 'us open': 3}

# Sparse matrix of bigram counts - each row corresponds to a document
term_count.toarray()
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

You could use a list comprehension to modify your dictionary2.

```
dictionary2 = [('Grand', 'Slam'), ('Australian', 'Open'), ('French', 'Open'), ('US', 'Open')]
dictionary2 = [' '.join(tup) for tup in dictionary2]

dictionary2
Out[26]: ['Grand Slam', 'Australian Open', 'French Open', 'US Open']
```

Edit: Based on the above I think you can use the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Modify dictionary2 to be compatible with CountVectorizer
dictionary2_cv = [' '.join(tup) for tup in dictionary2]

# Initialize and train CountVectorizer
cv2 = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2))
cv2.fit_transform(dictionary2_cv)

for row in range(start,end+1):
    report_name = fund_reports_table.loc[row, "report_names"]
    raw_report = open("F:/EDGAR_ShareholderReports/" + report_name, 'r', encoding="utf8").read()

    ## word for word
    temp = cv1.fit_transform([raw_report]).toarray()
    res1 = np.concatenate((res1,temp),axis=0)

    ## big grams
    bigram=set()
    sentences = raw_report.split(".")
    for line in sentences:
        token = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        bigram = bigram.union(set(list(ngrams(token, 2)))  )

    # Modify bigram to be compatible with CountVectorizer
    bigram = [' '.join(tup) for tup in bigram]

    # Note you must not fit_transform here - only transform using the trained cv2
    temp = cv2.transform(list(bigram)).toarray()
    res2=np.concatenate((res2,temp),axis=0)
```

Comment: I understand the nature of my problem a bit better now, but still the problem remains. Adding all docs in one "doc_set" is not feasible given the large number of documents. Also, the construction of the biggraams and the resulting vocabulary I would really prefer to do "manually". I fail to see how the inputs ("vocabulary" for CountVectorizer and the input for the fit_transform()) need to be, in order for the code to work

Comment: @SAFEX I have edited my answer with a possible solution based on your code. Note that you must not fit_transform after your CountVectorizer has been trained.